# Cannot reboot anymore

Tags: reboot

when I try to reboot - sometimes I get with ubuntu 16.04:

```
root@ligi-520i7:~# reboot 
Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.

root@ligi-520i7:~# systemctl status reboot.target
● reboot.target - Reboot
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

not sure what is going on there - and just switching off the laptop feels wrong - cannot shutdown via software either